# ERROR: Undefined procedure: PROLOG

Tags: prolog

Tengo estas lineas en un .pl

```
% Evitar warnings por Singletons
:- style_check(-singleton).

% Proceso de identificacion por casos...
identifica(X):-assert(estudio(pendiente)),id_estudio(X),purgar.

id_estudio(A):- nl,write("* Intentado con 
Tomografia..."),nl,tomografia(A),nl,write("*** LISTO!! Haz una Tomografía :) 
***"),nl,!.
id_estudio(A):- nl,write("* Intentado con 
Resonancia..."),nl,resonancia(A),nl,write("*** LISTO!! Haz una Resonancia :) 
***"),nl,!.
id_estudio(A):- nl,write("* Intentado con ECO..."),nl,eco(A),nl,write("*** 
LISTO!! Haz un ECO :) ***"),nl,!.
```

al momento de correr el programa, debo poner identifica(algo). y asi el sistema me ira preguntando por cada estudio, primero por tomografia, despues con resonancia y asi sucesivamente, pero al momento de correrlo me lanza este error

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: tomografia/1
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] tomografia(caida)
ERROR:    [9] id_estudio(caida) at 
c:/users/sergi/desktop/estudios_radiologicos.pl:9
ERROR:    [8] identifica(caida) at 
c:/users/sergi/desktop/estudios_radiologicos.pl:7
ERROR:    [7] <user>
     Exception: (10) tomografia(caida) ?
```

la linea 7 es esta

```
identifica(X):-assert(estudio(pendiente)),id_estudio(X),purgar.
```

y la linea 9 es:

```
id_estudio(A):- nl,write("* Intentado con 
Tomografia..."),nl,tomografia(A),nl,write("*** LISTO!! Haz una Tomografía :) 
***"),nl,!.
```

tengo otro programa que esta igualito, pero con otras variables y ese programa si me corre bien...ayuda, por favor :(

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined procedure: tomografia/1

esa parte te dice el problema, y es que esencialmente no tienes tu base de datos lógica cargada.

En ella lo más posible es que tengas tus registros de esta forma

```
tomografia('caida').
```

Para cargar una base de datos de otro archivo diferente del que estás actualmente debes de usar el predicado [load_files/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=load_files/2)